# Mathematical theories where paradoxes are formed from the assumptions of the system about itself

Tags: paradoxes

> There are in fact certain paradoxes involved in the notion of a system
> that predicts its own behaviour. These are reminiscent of Russell's Paradox
> in set theory and of the paradoxes that arise when one allows a statement
> to talk about itself (e.g., consider the statement, "This statement is false").
>
> Page-16 of the [Anti Tech Revolution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1944228004)

I think so the second example noted by the author is about the Godel's incompleteness theorem but reading the paragraph led me to wonder, are there examples other than these two where there is an occurrence of a paradox due to the logical system
making a statement about itself?